# Create self-signed x509 certificate

Tags: connected-apps, certificates, jwt

I am trying to get an access token by following the guide [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5). But I am stuck on the following

> The developer writes an app that generates a JWT. The JWT is signed with the X509 Certificate’s private key, and the connected app uses the certificate to verify the signature.

I know you can create a self-signed cert through salesforce but that never gives you a private key.

How do you create a self signed x509 certificate that you can upload to salesforce and use with your connected app?

Comment: From https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_about.htm&type=5: _You can export all your certificates and private keys into a keystore for storage or import certificates and keys from a keystore_

Comment: @identigral and once you export how you get the values, do you need an special program to open the downloaded file?

Comment: @manza https://keystore-explorer.org/

Comment: @identigral yeah I downloaded the program, i exported from certficate the file .jks and open it in the app. I can see all the certificates in there but to export the private key, I need that to generate the JWT token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use OpenSSL for that. On Linux/macOS, a script like this will generate multiple certificates, if you need them (for multiple environments in a CI/CD context, for example).

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo "Missing #1 argument (password)."
        exit 1
fi

echo "This script will output multiple certificates (canary, uat and production)."
echo "Country Name (2 letter code) []: "
read COUNTRY
echo "State or Province Name (full name) []: "
read STATE_PROVINCE
echo "Locality Name (eg, city) []: "
read LOCALITY
echo "Organization Name (eg, company) []: "
read ORG_NAME
echo "Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: "
read ORG_UNIT_NAME
echo "Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name) []: "
read COMMON_NAME
echo "Email Address []: "
read EMAIL

PASSWORD=$1

function generate () {

    mkdir assets
    mkdir assets/certificates

    # edit this line with all the targets you need 
    # (if you need more than one certificate, that is)
    # if you don't need more than one, then just follow the commands
    # inside this loop to generate your certificate
    for CERT_TARGET in "canary" "uat" "production"
    do
        # Generate a private key, and store it in a file called server.key.
        openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.pass.key 2048
        openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.pass.key -out assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.key

        # Generate a certificate signing request using the server.key file. Store the
        # certificate signing request in a file called server.csr. Enter information
        # about your company when prompted.
        openssl req -new -key assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.key -out assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.csr -subj "/C=$COUNTRY/ST=$STATE_PROVINCE/L=$LOCALITY/O=$ORG_NAME/OU=$ORG_UNIT_NAME/CN=$COMMON_NAME/emailAddress=$EMAIL"

        # Generate a self-signed digital certificate from the server.key and server.csr
        # files. Store the certificate in a file called server.crt.
        openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 730 -in assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.csr -signkey assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.key -out assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.crt

        # Encrypt the server private key
        openssl aes-256-cbc -k $PASSWORD -in assets/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.key -out assets/certificates/"$CERT_TARGET"_server.key.enc -e -md sha256
    done
}

generate
```

Of course, the downside of this sample script is that all certificates will be generated with the same password (and that's not good). Take that into consideration if you use it.

[Search for the equivalent commands on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355568/create-a-openssl-certificate-on-windows).

Comment: Generating a cert with openssl definitely helped, thanks.